# How does Font Book.app determine the "Design style" for a Smart Collection?

Tags: macos, font, font-book

In Font Book.app one of the criteria for creating a Smart Collection is "Design style".

[image: Font Book.app Smart Collection dialog]

How does Font Book.app determine whether or not a given font falls into one of the available categories?

Comment: Such a good question!  There is DEFINITELY no meta info embedded in these fonts that "matches up" with these "styles".  It must be embedded in some undocumented "database" used by FontBook, or provided by some Apple "service".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I figured it out...  Opening a font in [RoboFont](http://doc.robofont.com/download/), I scoured all the obscure meta-info available and finally found the entry that seems to correspond to what FontBook uses for the *Design Style* in the section called [Panose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PANOSE) (a term I had never heard of!).  Long story short... FontBook seems to probably use the `Proportion` to determine the style.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

That kind of info is often included in the metadata of the font file itself, especially in OTF files. It is usually the type designer or foundry that categorizes the font in the first place.

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail? I've read about some of the various OpenType tables but haven't grokked which tables would indicate that a font is monospaced for example.